# what does insert and commit do in Mybatis?

Tags: insert, mybatis, overhead

I did a test on the overhead of insert operation as well as commit operation.code snippets are as follows:

```
long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
session.insert("mybatis_test.BlogMapper.insert", new BlogMapper(4, "shuaige"));

long t3 = System.currentTimeMillis();
session.insert("mybatis_test.BlogMapper.insert", new BlogMapper(6, "shuaigege"));
long t4 = System.currentTimeMillis();
session.insert("mybatis_test.BlogMapper.insert", new BlogMapper(7, "shuaigegege"));
long t5 = System.currentTimeMillis();
session.commit();
long t6 = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

the System.out snippets are as follows:

```
System.out.println(t3-t2);
System.out.println(t4-t3);
System.out.println(t5-t4);
System.out.println(t6-t5);
```

and the output is:

869

1

1

205

As what we can see here, the very first 'insert' operation and the commit operation takes most of the overhead.but what does the first insert do so that it takes a lot of overhead?

Comment: What is DBMS? Can you try this using plain JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

The first insert opens de connection. Then it is reused during the duration of the session.

Answer (score 0):

technically the "insert" will do whatever is in the mapper..
the commit method will commit the sql to the database, without it nothing would actually be inserted, it may say (in eclipse for instance) that everything went well, but on the db, there wont be anything unless it got committed. hope that helps clearify